# RestAssured calling https get api giving Error

Tags: java, ssl, rest-assured

I have a https api 
I have inserted the certs in cacerts in my jdk 1.8
when I hit

```
Response response1 = RestAssured.given().log().all().get("someurl").then().log().ifError().extract().response();
```

Gives

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for  doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [Some other domain name]
>   Then i hit with relaxedHttpValidation and allowing all hostName

```
Response response = given().config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig(sslConfig().allowAllHostnames().relaxedHTTPSValidation())).log().all().get("someURL").then().log().ifError().extract().response();
```

It gives 503 service not available 
Am i missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution where we have to set the sni-header in request.
please follow the github url for the same 
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/pull/775

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the built in relaxedHTTPSValidation() method? It handles all the HTTPS related certificates.

Comment: Hey relaxedHTTPSValidation was not working. so just setting SNI header